# Facing an exception with Scanner in Java

Tags: java

i'm trying to execute this simple code but it gives me this exception and i can't resolve it , i've tried some solutions in others posts but with no result , so please some help

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

class test{

   public static void main(String args[]){


            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

                int a = sc.nextInt();
                String s = sc.next();
                int b = sc.nextInt();

                if(s.equals("*")){
                    System.out.println(a*b);
                }
                else if(s.equals("+")){
                    System.out.println(a+b);
                }
                else if(s.equals("-")){
                    System.out.println(a-b);
                }

                else if(s.equals("/")){
                    double a1 = a;
                    double b1 = b;

                    System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(a1/b1));
                }

        }               
    }
}
```

the exception  :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at test.main(test.java:14)
```

Comment: Scanner is iterating over tokens which are separated by delimiters. Default delimiter in Scanner is one or more whitespaces so `"1+2"` represents one token, `"1 + 2"` represent three tokens (because of spaces before and after `+`).

Comment: @azurefrog  i try those operation :   1 + 2 second one 1 * 3 third one 1 / 5 the 4th 2 - 1 each one in each line

Comment: @Pshemo i've did this but with no result

Comment: When I run your program with space delimited input it works fine.  When, exactly, are you getting the exception you posted?

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/YLGUrn

Answer (score -3):

you problem is the method next. it is expecting a deliminator. you can define it using the useDeliminator method.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Comment: Without defining it the default white space pattern is going to be used.